# "Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed"

Tags: android, android-cursor

I cannot understand this problem. I have tried to get the solution from other stackoverflow questions but failed to get the solution. I was not getting this error before. However, now I don't know what's wrong with the code stated below. Please help me with this. I'm stuck with this problem.

```
public void getAlbumsLists() {
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
    final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
    final String album_name = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ARTIST;
    final String tracks = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS;
    //  final String data=MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID; // NO
    // final String id1=MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID;
    final String tit = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM; //NO
    final String nam = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY; // NO
    final String typ = MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE; // NO
    final String art = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String artstkey = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST_KEY; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String frstyr = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.FIRST_YEAR; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String lstyr = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.LAST_YEAR; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String artstid = "artist_id"; //<<<< CAN GET

    final String[] columns = {"*"};

     Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
    // Lists the columns in the cursor
    for (String s : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
        Log.d("COLUMNS", "Column = " + s);
    }

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id)));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
        String artist2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist));
        String nr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tracks));
        String x = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album)));
        //String data1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        // String id2=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data));
        //String title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tit)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        //String name1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(nam)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        //String type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(typ)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        // AVAIALABLE COLUMNS
        String artwork = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(art)); //<<<< ADDED
        String artistkey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artstkey)); //<<<< ADDED
        String artistid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artstid)); //<<<< ADDED
        String minyear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(frstyr));
        String maxyear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(lstyr));

        s = new albumInfo(id, name, artist2, nr, artwork, x); // EXCLUDED
        albumList.add(s);

        cursor.close();
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(albumAdapter); // EXCLUDED
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android "attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921078/android-attempted-to-access-a-cursor-after-it-has-been-closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `cursor.close();` outside the while loop.

**Edited..**

First time after the while loop iterates the cursor is closed so you need to put it outside while.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest three improvement scenarios.

1. You need to move the cursor to first before accessing it for fetching data from the cursor.
2. You need to close the cursor when nothing is returned or the cursor is null.
3. Move the cursor close outside of your while loop.

So I would like to recommend you to rewrite the code like following.

```
// After you have fetched the data from cursor
if(cursor == null) return;
if(cursor.size() == 0) {
    cursor.close();
    return;
}

for (String s : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
    Log.d("COLUMNS", "Column = " + s);
}

// Move the cursor to the first position. 
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
    String id = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id)));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
    String artist2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist));
    String nr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tracks));
    String x = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album)));
    // ... Other code 
} while (cursor.moveToNext());

recyclerView1.setAdapter(albumAdapter); // EXCLUDED 

// Move the cursor outside of while loop
cursor.close();
```

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for pointing that out. Sorry I have missed that part.